# I'm trying to check to see whether a file exists in a directory on Linux Mint but recieve error

Tags: python, file, anaconda, linux-mint

I am attempting to see whether a file exists within a  directory then if it doesn't exist, create it. I'm using Anaconda and Python version 3.7.4. However when I run the code I recieve the error NameError: name 'found' is not defined. I'm using Visual Studio Code and am quite new to programming!

```
import fnmatch

import os

print()
for file in os.listdir('/home/user/CI6724_J0874321_John/'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'CI5232_Logs.txt'):
        found = True

if found:
    print('File exists')
else:
    open('/home/user/CI6724_J0874321_John/', 'w')
```

Comment: The short answer is that is not how you check for a file. The longer answer is in the link.

Comment: A few notes: you repeat `'/home/user/CI6724_J0874321_John/'`, define it once as a variable. `open('/home/user/CI6724_J0874321_John/', 'w')` will attempt to open a directory, which will fail. `found` may be not defined if the `if` branch is not executed (as pointed by meshkati's answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wont be easier to do directly this?

```
with open("/home/user/CI6724_J0874321_John/CI5232_Logs.txt", "w") as f:
    # rest of the code..
```

The context path will create the file directly if not exit and if exits will be open in writing mode.

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: Maybe OP is not familiar with contexts path.

Comment: the OP has several problems, (`found` variable, opening a directory for writing..), replacing "plain old open" with `with` is the least problem IMO.. but for sure `with open` is preferable

Comment: I’ve now solved the found issue! Thank you all for your help. Whereabouts would the with open, go in the code & what would it replace? Thank you again! I’ve only started Python recently

Comment: Nice, well [context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) save a lot of work, I will recommend to use it when opening  files.

Answer (score 0):

The `found` variable created within the `for` scope, so it's not accessible from outside of it.

Define it before your for loop, like:

```
import fnmatch

import os

found = False

print()
for file in os.listdir('/home/user/CI6724_J0874321_John/'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'CI5232_Logs.txt'):
        found = True

if found:
    print('File exists')
else:
    open('/home/user/CI6724_J0874321_John/', 'w')
```

Comment: This solved the problem! Thank you  I now receive the error IsADirectoryError: [Errno21] Is a directory: ‘/home/user...’